# Why does `iota(0) | take(0)` not model ranges::sized_range in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <ranges>

auto r = std::views::iota(0) | std::views::take(0);
static_assert(std::ranges::sized_range<decltype(r)>);
```

gcc-trunk [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/4E6833e77) it for *required-expression* [`std::ranges::size(r)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/size) is invalid. Why does `r` not model [`ranges::sized_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/sized_range), i,e, why can't I use `std::ranges::size` on it?

### Update

Compiles after using [range-v3](https://godbolt.org/z/1qbxfEeeb). Is this feature required for C++23, or is it an LWG issue?

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <ranges>

auto r = ranges::views::iota(0) | ranges::views::take(0);
static_assert(std::ranges::sized_range<decltype(r)>);
```

The problem seems to be that the `sentinel_t` of `r` in `range-v3` is just `ranges::default_sentinel` which satisfies the [`std::sized_sentinel_for<ranges::counted_iterator>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sized_sentinel_for), since there is a valid `operator-` in [[predef.iterators#iterators.counted]](http://eel.is/c++draft/predef.iterators#iterators.counted) for those two types:

> ```
> friend constexpr iter_difference_t<I> operator-(
>   const counted_iterator& x, default_sentinel_t);
> friend constexpr iter_difference_t<I> operator-(
>   default_sentinel_t, const counted_iterator& y);
> ```

But in `namepace std::ranges`, the `sentinel_t` of `r` is `std::ranges::take_view<std::ranges::iota_view>::_Sentinel<true>` which cannot convert to `std::default_sentinel_t`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`views::take` only yields a sized range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view) if the given range itself was sized. And `views::iota` [isn't a sized range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) unless you use one of the two-element constructors that give it a size. Which you did not.

As for why `take_view` is only sized if the underlying iterator is sized, this is because `take_view` stops when the number of elements to take is reached *or* you reach the end of the underlying range. Which means that the size could be less than what you asked for. So to compute the size of a `take_view`, you must be able to compute the size of the underlying range to see if it is less than the given count. It doesn't matter if you just so happen to pass a count that will never need to compute the size; it's a compile-time property, not based on the value you happened to give it at runtime.

How this "works" for Range V3 is unknown, but the C++20 standard doesn't permit it to work.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But if we know that the `sentinel` of the upstream `range` is unreachable at compile-time, shouldn't we think that we can get its size at a constant time after applying `take_view`? Since this is obviously a conversion from infinite to finite.

Comment: @康桓瑋 That is *possible*, but not what the committee chose to specify

Answer (score 6):

> Compiles after using range-v3. Is this feature required for C++23, or is it an LWG issue?

No and no.

`take(0)` is kind of a weird example since it suggests that the `0` might be important -- if we could take decisions based on the value then `take(0)` would always just give you `empty<T>` for the right `T` (which is a `sized_range`).

So let's instead consider [take(5)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsHc2IGmk60).

`take(5)` gives you a range with *at most* `5` elements. But we can only know how many if we know how many elements are in the input range, and we can only know that if the input range is a `sized_range`, which is how C++20's `take` operates. But there is actually another way that we can know how many elements `r | take(5)` has without `r` being a `sized_range`: if we know that `r` is an *infinite* range. Obviously taking `5` elements out of an infinite range would give you a range of with `5` elements (last I checked, infinity is in fact larger than `5`, even for very large values of `5`).

In range-v3, `iota(0)` is an infinite range. I mean, it is an infinite range in C++20 as well, but C++20 Ranges does not have this notion of infinite ranges while [range-v3 does](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/1120609c7cb5dee9d2d216c579e935475cc39c4e/include/range/v3/view/iota.hpp#L330-L338):

```cpp
template<typename From, typename To /* = unreachable_sentinel_t*/>
struct RANGES_EMPTY_BASES iota_view
  : view_facade<iota_view<From, To>,
                same_as<To, unreachable_sentinel_t>
                    ? infinite
                    : std::is_integral<From>::value && std::is_integral<To>::value
                          ? finite
                          : unknown>
{
```

Our case here satisfies `same_as<To, unreachable_sentinel_t>`, so we're passing `infinite` into what range-v3 refers to as "cardinality".

`take` then detects that [its input is infinite](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/1120609c7cb5dee9d2d216c579e935475cc39c4e/include/range/v3/view/take.hpp#L249-L250) and returns `default_sentinel` as the sentinel:

```cpp
CPP_auto_member
constexpr auto CPP_fun(end)()(const //
    requires range<Rng const>)
{
    if constexpr(sized_range<Rng const>)
        if constexpr(random_access_range<Rng const>)
            return ranges::begin(base_) +
                   static_cast<range_difference_t<Rng>>(size());
        else
            return default_sentinel;
    // Not to spec: Infinite ranges:
    else if constexpr(is_infinite<Rng const>::value)
        return default_sentinel;
    else
        return sentinel<true>{ranges::end(base_)};
}
```

So in this case, our `iterator`/`sentinel` pair is `counted_iterator`/`default_sentinel`, this pair satisfies `sized_sentinel_for`, so `ranges::size` works. These are equal when [the count hits zero](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/1120609c7cb5dee9d2d216c579e935475cc39c4e/include/range/v3/iterator/counted_iterator.hpp#L328-L332) and subtraction simply [negates the count](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/1120609c7cb5dee9d2d216c579e935475cc39c4e/include/range/v3/iterator/counted_iterator.hpp#L406-L418).

C++20 simply, by design, does not have this notion of infinite ranges. It is unclear if it will or not in the future. I'm not even sure that Eric Niebler and Casey Carter were happy with the design in range-v3.